# Java HttpsServer multi threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, http, https, threadpoolexecutor

I have set up an HttpsServer in Java. All of my communication works perfectly. I set up multiple contexts, load a self-signed certificate, and even start up based on an external configuration file.

My problem now is getting multiple clients to be able to hit my secure server. To do so, I would like to somehow multi-thread the requests that come in from the HttpsServer but cannot figure out how to do so. Below is my basic HttpsConfiguration.

```
  HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(secureConnection.getPort()), 0);
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

  sslContext.init(secureConnection.getKeyManager().getKeyManagers(), secureConnection.getTrustManager().getTrustManagers(), null);

  server.setHttpsConfigurator(new SecureServerConfiguration(sslContext));
  server.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
  server.createContext("/test", new TestHandler());
  server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
  server.start();
```

Where secureConnection is a custom class containing server setup and certificate information.

I attempted to set the executor to `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and a couple of other ones. However, they all produced the same result. Each managed the threads differently but the first request had to finish before the second could process.

I also tried writing my own Executor

```
public class AsyncExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor implements Executor
{
   public static Executor create()
   {
      return new AsyncExecutor();
   }

   public AsyncExecutor()
   {
      super(5, 10, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(12));
   }

   @Override
   public void execute(Runnable process)
   {
      System.out.println("New Process");

      Thread newProcess = new Thread(process);
      newProcess.setDaemon(false);

      newProcess.start();

      System.out.println("Thread created");
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, with the same result as the other Executors.

To test I am using Postman to hit the /Test endpoint which is simulating a long running task by doing a `Thread.sleep(10000)`. While that is running, I am using my Chrome browser to hit the root endpoint. The root page does not load until the 10 second sleep is over.

Any thoughts on how to handle multiple concurrent requests to the HTTPS server?

For ease of testing, I replicated my scenario using the standard HttpServer and condensed everything into a single java program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Example
{
   private final static int PORT = 80;
   private final static int BACKLOG = 10;

   /**
    * To test hit:
    * <p><b>http://localhost/test</b></p>
    * <p>This will hit the endoint with the thread sleep<br>
    * Then hit:</p>
    * <p><b>http://localhost</b></p>
    * <p>I would expect this to come back right away. However, it does not come back until the
    * first request finishes. This can be tested with only a basic browser.</p>
    * @param args
    * @throws Exception
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      new Example().start();
   }

   private void start() throws Exception
   {
      HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(PORT), BACKLOG);

      server.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
      server.createContext("/test", new TestHandler());
      server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
      server.start();

      System.out.println("Server Started on " + PORT);
   }

   class RootHandler implements HttpHandler
   {
      @Override
      public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException
      {
         String body = "<html>Hello World</html>";

         httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, body.length());
         OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();

         outputStream.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         outputStream.close();
      }
   }

   class TestHandler implements HttpHandler
   {
      @Override
      public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException
      {
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         String body = "<html>Test Handled</html>";

         httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, body.length());
         OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();

         outputStream.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         outputStream.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to add some source code showing how you setup the port handling and actually process individual requests in your http server: for all we know you only accept a single socket at a time.

Comment: How could I change the HttpsServer to accept multiple sockets?

Comment: It already does. How are you *handling* the accepted sockets?

Comment: I am not doing any manipulation of the sockets myself. I assumed the HttpsServer would handle it already for me.

Comment: I am still unable to resolve this issue. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** It's OK, just use two different browsers, or specialized tool to test it.

You original implementation is OK and it work as expected, no custom Executor needed. For each request it executes method of "shared" handler class instance. It always picks up free thread from pool, so each method call is executed in different thread.

The problem seems to be, that when you use multiple windows of the same browser to test this behavior... for some reason requests get executed in serialised way (only one at the time). Tested with latest Firefox, Chrome, Edge and Postman. Edge and Postman work as expected. Also anonymous mode of Firefox and Chrome helps.

Same local URL opened at the same time from two Chrome windows. In first the page loaded after 5s, I got Thread.sleep(5000) so that's OK. Second window loaded respons in 8,71s, so there is 3,71s delay of unknown origin.

[image: Chrome windows 1]
[image: Chrome windows 2]

My guess? Probably some browser internal optimization or failsafe mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a non-zero maximum backlog (the second argument to `create()`):

```
HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(secureConnection.getPort()), 10);
```

Comment: I had played around with this as well. This pertains to the backlog associated with the server. I even went as far as testing up to 1000 for this field. I am still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and what works for me is:

```
public void handler(HttpExchange exchange) {
    executor.submit(new SomeOtherHandler());
}

public class SomeOtherHandler implements Runnable {

}
```

where the executor is the one you created as thread pool.